# How can I get my array as a *nice* human readable list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of allowed file extensions that can be uploaded to my site.

I check them with [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

I'm displaying an error message if they choose a non supported extension.

It looks like

```
var msg = 'You may only upload files of type ' + allowedExt.join(', ');
```

Obviously the list doesn't look too flash. I'd like it to look more *human readable*.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simpler way to do the [answer posted by alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765534/how-can-i-get-my-array-as-a-nice-human-readable-list-in-javascript/3765539#3765539) is by using [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to get the last element off:

```
var niceList = function(array, join, finalJoin) {
    var arr = array.slice(0), last = arr.pop();
    join = join || ', ';
    finalJoin = finalJoin || ' and ';
    return arr.join(join) + finalJoin + last;    
};
```

Comment: This is very nice. Plenty of user options and a readable array all in basically 4 lines.

Comment: Do you mean when you say it changes the array, it only changes it within the function's scope right? It is passed by value right?

Comment: I vote to remove first half of this answer.  I highly doubt @Alex wants to modify an array used elsewhere for validation.

Comment: @alex - nope it'll change the original array, here's a test of the first version:  http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/NKYTP/1/ and the second, which doesn't mutate: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/NKYTP/2/

Comment: @Josh - fair point, the extra cost is almost *always* worth the safety, removed the first non-copy option.

Comment: Congrats too Nick! Now get off here and spend some time with the wife! :D

Comment: Should this do a `if (array.length == 1) return array[0]` ?

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer does not handle a one item list very well.

```
function niceList(array) {
  if (!array || array.length == 0) return "";
  var clone = array.slice(0);

  return function build() {
    if (clone.length == 1) return clone[0];
    if (clone.length == 2) return clone[0] + ' and ' + clone[1];
    return clone.shift() + ", " + build();
  }();  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just another way to do it.

Cases considered:

- [] -> ""
- [""] -> ""
- ["A"] -> "A"
- ["A", "B"] -> "A and B"
- ["A", "B", "C"] -> "A, B and C"

... and so on

```
function niceList(a) {
    return [
            a

            /* Get all the elements except the last one.
             * If there is just one element, get that
             */
            .slice(0, a.length - 1 || 1)

            /* Create a comma separated string from these elements */
            .join(", ")
        ]
        /* Process the last element (if there is one) and concat it
         * with the processed first part.
         */
        .concat(
            a

            /* Create a copy */
            .slice()

            /* Take the last element, if there is one */
            .splice(-1, Number(a.length > 1))
        )

        /* Join the two processed parts */
        .join(" and ");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since we're apparently providing different versions of alex's answer, here's one without `join`:

```
function niceList(array, join, final) {
   return array.reduce(function (pv, cv, i, a) { 
      return pv + (i == a.length - 1 ? final : join) + cv; 
   });
};
```

Doesn't work with old browsers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can!

```
var niceList = function(array, join, finalJoin) {       
    join = join || ', ';
    finalJoin = finalJoin || ' and ';       
    var length = array.length;      
    return array.slice(0, length - 1).join(join) + finalJoin + array[length - 1];    
};

alert(niceList([a, b, c])); // 'a, b and c'
```

Answer (score 0):

I took you literally and made it into an actual HTML list.

```
var extensions = ['html', 'txt', 'png', 'jpg'];
var extension_list = '<ul>';

for(i=0; i<extensions.length; i++)
{
    extension_list += '<li>'+extensions[i]+'</li>';
}

extension_list += '<ul>';

var msg = '<p>Sorry, you can only upload the following extensions:</p>'+extension_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this answer needs some air time, in 2022, we have an API for that, which supports multiple languages and conventions (which could be determined for each individual user).

The `Intl.ListFormat` API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/ListFormat

Usage example as follows:

```
const allowedExt = [
    '.jpeg',
    '.png',
    '.gif',
    '.webp'
]
```

```
const listFormatter = new Intl.ListFormat('en', {
    style: 'long',
    type: 'conjunction'
})
```

```
listFormatter.format(allowedExt)
// .jpeg, .png, .gif, and .webp
```